# Can the basis of $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb R$ be written as a $2\times2$ matrix where the first column is Reals and second is Complex?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, real-numbers

this might be a dumb question but I'm taking linear algebra right now and online I'm reading how the basis of C over R is {1,i}. I'm wondering if this is equivalent to

$$M =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & i
  \end{bmatrix}$$

If no, why not? The reason I ask is because in R2 we represent our unit vectors $i$ and $j$ as our basis vectors like so

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}

and so geometrically if we take a unit vector in the $x$ and $y$ directions like in the case of our unit vectors $i$ and $j$, but now for $\Bbb C$, it seems natural to me that we represent it as a $2$ dimensional matrix with reals in the first column and complex numbers in the second since our $y$-axis correspond to the complex numbers and $x$-axis to reals, if that makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$, then a "basis for $V$ over $k$" is a set of elements of $V$. In particular, $\{1,i\}$ is a set of elements of $\Bbb C$, but a matrix is not a set of elements of $\Bbb C$ so cannot be a basis. Even if you mean the columns of that matrix, those are still elements of $\Bbb C^2$, not of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thanks, I think that clarified it quite a bit, but if a basis is a set of elements of V and we represent it as such in the case of ℂ, why are we permitted to use the two column vectors in the context of R2, for example? is it just equivalent to {(1,0),(0,1)}? And given what you said, a basis for R could be written as {1}, but not a column vector with 1,0 since that is apart of R2

Answer (score 1):

This might help to settle your doubts: Each complex numbers can be considered as a vector space  over the reals since you can choose a pair of linearly independent set of vectors, say $1$ and $i$, then when $z\in\mathbb C$ one has $z=a+bi$ as a unique linear combination, for any $z$.

If one choose another set of generator for $\mathbb C$,  this means a change of basis, where one chooses an assignment
$$1\mapsto a+bi,$$
$$i \mapsto c+di.$$
Then associated a this change there is a matrix that codes this information,
the matrix of this base change is precisely
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&c\\ b&d\end{array}\right],$$
which it has not complex pure imaginary components, and whose determinant $ad-bc\neq0$ to asure linear independence.